# How to write address in Italian?

Tags: translation

I want to write my address in Italian but don't know how. I searched on Google but  I got confused  because  a few sites had different answers. The problem is that I don't know the structure of how to write an address in Italian. I know that the addresses in America have a different order than Italy but don't know how people write it in Italy.

Can anyone explain how to write an address in Italian and show me the steps, how to transform an address, written according to the American order, into the Italian order address?

Comment: Please [read](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) very carefully, what kind of questions are on-topic for this site. Please take into account that the questions about simple proofreading, writing advice, and translation requests are off-topic. Please make an effort to research your question and show which details are still unclear to you to ensure that you'll get better answers.

Comment: No, I mean that this question doesn't really show your own efforts to investigate this issue, using Google, an Italian textbook, or a writing manual. The StackExchange network is here for you to solve any problems and eliminate doubts that are unsolvable with basic sources. This question can be answered [using Google](https://www.google.se/search?q=writing+an+italian+address) in about 2 seconds, and gives you [plenty of examples](http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats/italy/). If other sources don't satisfy you, then please go ahead and ask a specific question here.

Comment: Dear @Tia27, to get this question reopened, please specify **as many details as possible**: what exactly is still unclear in the examples found via Google? Do you have a problem with the structure of address? Would you like to find a rule of writing an American state as an Italian province? Do you have difficulties in understanding some words? Specifically: what is/are the issue(s)?

Comment: @Tia27, do you know that Google doesn't, in itself, “say” anything, do you? However, it may point to useful sites, such as that mentioned by I.M. and several more. Would you care to make a single, concrete example of something that you'd like to know about addresses and that that website doesn't explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to write it like this:
Via/Corso (meaning street)/Viale (boulevard)/Piazza (square) [road] (,) [civic number], [city] ([abbreviation of province*]).
For example:

- Via Garibaldi 374, Torino (TO)
- Piazza San Pietro, 325, Cerveteri (RM)

You can also add the CAP (Postal Code) of the city before its name if you want to.

*You can omit the abbreviation if the city is a province.

Comment: There is often no comma between the street and the number. The postal code goes before the city name.

Comment: BTW, if it's to write a letter the CAP is almost mandatory nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's start from the street and civic number, so like
*Via Dante Alighieri 28*
Sometimes ther are also appartments, room number, scale and so on, so you need to add as additional string, something like:
*App. 12, Piano 1*
Next you will go to CAP, City, Province which is
*23900 Lecco (LC)*
LC - is the province code, all with 2 letters. You can find the province codes in the Internet. It is uncommon but will be not a mistake if you will write province completely as Lecco (Lecco)
So you have all local address, you can just add "Italy" if it is for abroad