# What is the format to send a parcel to Italy?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Hi I have this address here:

- Name Surname
- building
- Chieri TO 10023
- Italy

I have removed bits to hide their information. 
What is the city, postcode and state of the address?

Comment: The address should have the postcode before the place name: “10023 Chieri TO”. However, this is about the postal system, not the Italian language.

Comment: Related: [How to write address in Italian?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/how-to-write-address-in-italian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The city is Chieri in the Torino’s province (which abbreviation is TO) and the post code is 10023.

Each province in Italy as a two characters abbreviation.

Also the post code is a five digits number that follows a sort of rule for which the principal city of each province has a post code ending in 100. For example for Torino the post code is 10100 and each city in this province has a five digits post code starting with 10.

The state is obviously Italy.

Comment: The post code 10100 is invalid: the town is subdivided into zones with different post codes of the type 101xy.

Comment: Maybe you’re right for very big cities like Turin, Milan or Rome but, for example, for Savona where I live we have 17100 no matter the zone you live

Comment: Yes, large cities use different post codes with just the first three digits in common (001xx for Roma, 101xx for Turin, 201xx for Milan), while the xxx00 form is just nominal (and perhaps used by some public institutions).

Comment: Non ne ero sicuro, ma ho controllato: dal 2009 [la sigla di Barletta-Andria-Trani è BT](http://www.lagazzettadelmezzogiorno.it/news/home/140192/non-piu-bat-ma-bt-sesta-provincia-di-puglia-cambia-sigla.html).

Comment: Ok, correggo la risposta